# Very slow query with TOP and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, top-n

I have a query in SQL Server 2014 that takes a lot of time to get the results when I execute it.

When I remove the `TOP`or the `ORDER BY`intructions, it executes faster, but if I write both of them, it takes a lot of time.

```sql
SELECT TOP (10) A.ColumnValue AS ValueA
FROM TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN TableB AS B
        ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.DateValue > '1982-05-02'
ORDER BY ValueA
```

How could I make it faster?

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: Do you have indices on `A.DateValue` and `A.ColumnValue`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say

> When I remove the TOP *or* the ORDER BY ... it executes faster

Which would indicate that SQL Server has no problem generating the entire result set in the desired order. It just goes pear shaped with the limiting of `TOP 10`. This is a common issue with [rowgoals](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals). When SQL Server knows you just need the first few results it can choose a different plan attempting to optimise for this case that can backfire.

More recent versions include the hint `DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL` to disable this on a per query basis. On older versions you can use `QUERYTRACEON 4138` as below.

```
SELECT TOP (10) A.ColumnValue AS ValueA
FROM TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN TableB AS B
        ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.DateValue > '1982-05-02'
ORDER BY ValueA
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 4138)
```

You can use this to verify the cause but may find permissions to run `QUERYTRACEON` are a problem.

In that eventuality you can hide the `TOP` value in a variable as below

```
DECLARE @Top INT = 10

SELECT TOP (@Top) A.ColumnValue AS ValueA
FROM TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN TableB AS B
        ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.DateValue > '1982-05-02'
ORDER BY ValueA
option (optimize for (@Top = 1000000))
```

Answer (score 1):

create the index based on `ID` column of both tables

```
    CREATE INDEX index_nameA
    ON TableA (ID, DateValue)
;
    CREATE INDEX index_nameB
    ON TableB (ID)
```

it will create better plan in times of query execution

Comment: @AlbertoMuñozSánchez then share the execution plan in question

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use the indexes to improve performance.
Here, in this case, the index can be put on (date_value).
For uses of indexes refer to this URL:[using indexes](https://www.guru99.com/indexes.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty hopeless, unless most of your data has an earlier date.  If the date is special, you could create a computed persisted column to speed up the query in general.  However, I doubt that is the case.

I can envision a better execution plan for the query phrased this way:

```
SELECT TOP (10) A.ColumnValue AS ValueA
FROM TableA A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE A.ID = B.ID) AND
      A.DateValue > '1982-05-02'
ORDER BY ValueA;
```

with an indexes on `TableA(ValueA, DateValue, Id, ColumnValue)` and `TableB(id)`.  That execution plan would scan the index from the beginning and then do the test on `DateValue` and `Id` and return `ColumnValue` for the corresponding matching rows.

However, I don't think SQL Server would generate this plan (although it is worth a try), and I don't know how to force it if it doesn't.